# Remove class from DIV when it's below certain index

Tags: jquery

It's really hard to explain for me what I want so I made a fiddle and there's also a live example. My fiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/a31anx7n/2/

After clicking on div and moving mouse done, all divs that was hovered gets class `highlight`. That's ok and I'm happy with it. Hovewer then I go up divs whose were highlighted stays highlighted. I want to remove class from this divs. How do I do it ? Please check live example and you will understand what I'm trying to achieve:

http://wordpressbooking.systems/example/default-calendar/ `(scroll a little bit down for demo)`

Code

```
var clicked = false;
var cindex = 0;
var lastone = 0;
var index = 0;
var index2 = 0;

$('.td').click(function() {
    clicked = true;
    cindex = $(this).index();
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});

$('.td').hover(function() {
    if(clicked) {
        index = $(this).index();
        if(index > cindex) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }
    }
}, function () {
    if(clicked) {
        index2 = $(this).index();
        if(index2 > lastone) {
            //$('.td').removeClass('highlight');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Code relevant to understanding the question should be pasted directly into your question, not available only in an external resource.  This is a StackOverflow guideline that helps keep StackOverflow questions relevant as a knowledge resource long after external links are no longer functional or have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am off to bed, but have a look at this

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/bfn0ussy/)

```
$('.td').hover(function() {
    if(clicked) {
        index = $(this).index();
        if(index > cindex) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('highlight');
    } 
});
```